# Fourier Derivative of Discrete Values in Python

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, smoothing, derivative

I am attempting to find the time derivative of physical system measurements in the Fourier domain. The system can be modeled as an ODE and has a periodic solution.

$$\frac{d}{d t} y{\left(t \right)} = - A \left(y{\left(t \right)}  + K \sin{\left(B t \right)}- C \right)$$

Using the analytical solution, I generated test measurement data and the exact time derivative values at each time step. For now, the test data has no noise but ultimately, some sort of smoothing or filtering will be applied in the Fourier space.

I am unable to get my result to match the true value of the derivative. For practical help on implementation, [I followed this article](https://nirpyresearch.com/fourier-spectral-smoothing-method/) which goes over some basic theory and provides an example in python that I applied to my problem. Here is the code I used:

### Generate test data from analytical solution:

```
datasetName='testData'
outputPath='../'+datasetName
ti=0
tf=50
T_0=400
timeStep=0.100
f=0.1
K=50
t=np.arange(ti,tf+timeStep,timeStep)
T_b=-1*K*np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t)+T_0
T_w_0=300
density=1358
specificHeat=8933
radius=0.02
thickness=1e-3
h=2000
a_v=(2*radius)/(thickness**2+2*thickness*radius)
A= -1*(h*a_v)/(density*specificHeat)
B=2*np.pi*f
C=T_0
D=T_w_0
solidTemp=-A**2*K*np.sin(B*t)/(A**2 + B**2) - A*B*K*np.cos(B*t)/(A**2 + B**2) + C + (-A**2*C + A**2*D + A*B*K - B**2*C + B**2*D)*np.exp(A*t)/(A**2 + B**2)
solidTempDerivative=-1*((h*a_v)/(density*specificHeat))*(T_w-T_b)
```

### Application of Fourier derivative theorem

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter, general_gaussian
X=solidTemp[:-1]
tt=time[:-1]
sigma = 40
m = 1

XX = np.hstack((X,np.flip(X)))

qq =2*np.pi*np.arange(-XX.shape[0]//2,XX.shape[0]//2,1)/XX.shape[0]

# Define a new window
win1 = np.roll(general_gaussian(XX.shape[0], m, 0.5*sigma), XX.shape[0]//2)

# Calculate FFT and multiply by -q^2
f2XX = np.roll(np.roll(fXX, -XX.shape[0]//2)*(-qq**2),XX.shape[0]//2)

# Multiply by the window and inverse FFT
XXf2 = np.real(np.fft.ifft(f2XX*win1))[:X.shape[0]]
plt.plot(tt, XXf2)
```

Inverse FTT result:

[image: Inverse FTT after Fourier derivative]

True derivative:

[image: True derivative]